# Repository transfer: how do I get to the inbox of a Bitbucket team?

Tags: bitbucket

Here's the background:

I've got a private repository up on Bitbucket under my personal account, but other developers will be working with it soon. So I created a team for the project and added the other developers, with myself as team admin.

Then I initiated a transfer of the repository from my account to the team account.

The repo URL updated as I expected, e.g. was
`https://bitbucket.org/mike/projectname/project.git`
and is now `https://bitbucket.org/teamname/projectname/project.git`.

But the transfer is just sitting there on the Settings page in an unfinished state, because I don't know how to accept the transfer on behalf of the team!

The team does not have an email address attached, and following the steps in the Bitbucket doc (https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/log-in-to-manage-an-individual-account-or-a-team-311034081.html) doesn't help me see the contents of the team inbox.

Is there something incredibly simple I've blindly overlooked?